# How can I add a new column into the DataFrame that has two levels?

Tags: python, pandas, yfinance

I'm trying to insert a new column in a DataFrame that holds other DataFrames inside.

I have Data for two ETFs, the SPY and DBC.
I'm trying to insert a new set of Data in the SPY DataFrame, but I'm getting a warning message.

In the end what I'm looking for is to get for SPY, columns (Open, High, Low, Adj Close, Volume and MA).

Thanks,

Steve

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date
import numpy as np

tickers = ['SPY','DBC']
start_date = "2000-01-01"
end_date = str(date.today())
df = pd.DataFrame()
df = yf.download(tickers,start=start_date,end=end_date, group_by='ticker')
df = df.fillna(method='ffill')
df.dropna(inplace=True)

df['DBC']['MA'] = np.nan
```

I get:

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

Answer (score 3):

```
df.loc[:,('DBC', 'MA')] = np.nan
```

As already your warning message says, you need to use `.loc[row_indexer, col_indexer]`. For multileveled indexes or columns you need to specify the indexer as tuples.
[Here is why you need to use loc.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy)